# comparing two lists and searching by a field, Python

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two files I wish to compare and then produce a specific output:

1) Below are the contents of the username text file (this stores the latest films viewed by the user)

```
    Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet
    Sci-Fi,Solaris
    Romance, When Harry met Sally
```

2) Below are the contents of the films.txt file which stores all the films in the program that are available to the user

```
0,Genre, Title, Rating, Likes
1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG,3
2,Sci-Fi,Solaris, PG,0
3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG,0
4,Sci-Fi,Cosmos, PG,0
5,Drama, The English Patient, 15,0
6,Drama, Benhur, PG,0
7,Drama, The Pursuit of Happiness, 12, 0
8,Drama, The Thin Red Line, 18,0
9,Romance, When Harry met Sally, 12, 0
10,Romance, You've got mail, 12, 0
11,Romance, Last Tango in Paris, 18, 0
12,Romance, Casablanca, 12, 0
```

An example of the output I require: The user has currently viewed two sci-fi and one Romance film. The output therefore should SEARCH the Films text file by Genre (identifying SCI-FI and ROMANCE), and should list the films in the films.txt file which have NOT been viewed by the user yet. In this case

```
3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG,0
4,Sci-Fi,Cosmos, PG,0
10,Romance, You've got mail, 12, 0
11,Romance, Last Tango in Paris, 18, 0
12,Romance, Casablanca, 12, 0
```

I have the following code which attempts to do the above, but the output it produces is incorrect:

```
def viewrecs(username):
   #set the username variable to the text file -to use it in the next bit
   username = (username + ".txt")
   #open the username file that stores latest viewings
   with open(username,"r") as f:
      #open the csv file reader for the username file
          fReader=csv.reader(f)
          #for each row in the fReader
          for row in fReader:
             #set the genre variable to the row[0], in which row[0] is all the genres (column 1 in username file)
             genre=row[0]
             #next, open the films file
             with open("films.txt","r") as films:
                #open the csv reader for this file (filmsReader as opposed to fReader)
                filmsReader=csv.reader(films)
                #for each row in the films file
                for row in filmsReader:
                   #and for each field in the row 
                   for field in row:
                      #print(field)
                      #print(genre)
                      #print(field[0])
                      if genre in field and row[2] not in fReader:
                         print(row)
```

Output (undesired):

```
['1', 'Sci-Fi', 'Out of the Silent Planet', ' PG', '3']
['2', 'Sci-Fi', 'Solaris', ' PG', '0']
['3', 'Sci-Fi', 'Star Trek', ' PG', '0']
['4', 'Sci-Fi', 'Cosmos', ' PG', '0']
```

I don't want a re-write or new solution, but, preferably, a fix to the above solution with its logical progression ...

@gipsy - your solution appears to have nearly worked. I used:

```
def viewrecs(username):

  #set the username variable to the text file -to use it in the next bit
  username = (username + ".txt")
  #open the username file that stores latest viewings
  lookup_set = set()
  with open(username,"r") as f:
    #open the csv file reader for the username file
    fReader=csv.reader(f)
    #for each row in the fReader
    for row in fReader:
      genre = row[1]
      name = row[2]
      lookup_set.add('%s-%s' % (genre, name))
  with open("films.txt","r") as films:
    filmsReader=csv.reader(films)
    #for each row in the films file
    for row in filmsReader:
      genre = row[1]
      name = row[2]
      lookup_key = '%s-%s' % (genre, name)
      if lookup_key not in lookup_set:
        print(row)
```

The output is as below: It is printing ALL the lines in allfilms that are not in the first set, rather than just the ones based on the GENRE in the first set:

```
['0', 'Genre', ' Title', ' Rating', ' Likes']
['3', 'Sci-Fi', 'Star Trek', ' PG', ' 0']
['4', 'Sci-Fi', 'Cosmos', ' PG', ' 0']
['5', 'Drama', ' The English Patient', ' 15', ' 0']
['6', 'Drama', ' Benhur', ' PG', ' 0']
['7', 'Drama', ' The Pursuit of Happiness', ' 12', ' 0']
['8', 'Drama', ' The Thin Red Line', ' 18', ' 0']
['10', 'Romance', " You've got mail", ' 12', ' 0']
['11', 'Romance', ' Last Tango in Paris', ' 18', ' 0']
['12', 'Romance', ' Casablanca', ' 12', ' 0']
```

NOTE: I changed the format of the first set to be the same, for simplicity, of the all films entries:

```
1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG
2,Sci-Fi,Solaris, PG
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using sets and separate lists to filter movies in appropriate genres that were not seen? We can even abuse the dictionaries' `keys` and `values` for this purpose:

```
def parse_file (file):
    return map(lambda x: [w.strip() for w in x.split(',')], open(file).read().split('\n'))

def movies_to_see ():
    seen = {film[0]: film[1] for film in parse_file('seen.txt')}
    films = parse_file('films.txt')
    to_see = []

    for film in films:
        if film[1] in seen.keys() and film[2] not in seen.values():
            to_see.append(film)
    return to_see
```

Comment: `movies_to_see` is the method, `to_see` is the array it returns.

Comment: I am not familiar with lambda and the use of maps, so again, commenting each line would be very helpful. I would try this but it is not obvious where to implement it and its meaning ...

Comment: Parse file simply yields a list of list where every sublist is a coma separated line from the file received as argument, and movies_to_see returns the output you wanted by your post

Answer (score 0):

Okay ,  build a set going through the first file with Genre  + name as the entry.

Now iterate over the second file and lookup in the set you made above for an entry for Genre+ name, if not exists print that out.

Once I am home I can type some code.

As promised my code for this is below:

```
def viewrecs(username):
  #set the username variable to the text file -to use it in the next bit
  username = (username + ".txt")
  # In this set we will collect the unique combinations of genre and name
  genre_name_lookup_set = set()
  # In this set we will collect the unique genres 
  genre_lookup_set = set()
  with open(username,"r") as f:
    #open the csv file reader for the username file
    fReader=csv.reader(f)
    #for each row in the fReader
    for row in fReader:
      genre = row[0]
      name = row[1]
      # Add the genre name combination to this set, duplicates will be taken care automatically as set won't allow dupes  
      genre_name_lookup_set.add('%s-%s' % (genre, name))
      # Add genre to this set
      genre_lookup_set.add(genre)
  with open("films.txt","r") as films:
    filmsReader=csv.reader(films)
    #for each row in the films file
    for row in filmsReader:
      genre = row[1]
      name = row[2]
      # Build a lookup key using genre and name, example:Sci-Fi-Solaris
      lookup_key = '%s-%s' % (genre, name)
      if lookup_key not in genre_name_lookup_set and genre in genre_lookup_set:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for this answer to be comprehensible. Gener = Genre? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes. I mean genre.

Comment: @pythoncarrot My answer updated with code. Please take a look

Comment: Thank you - however, the following error occurred on trying your code:     lookup_set.add('%-%' % (genre, name))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting   *Also, could you explain what the    "('%-%' %" bit does?

Comment: it worked! Nearly .... I had to add an "s" after each % to adjust the formatting issue I was having earlier. The problem now is that is printing EVERY film in the films file that is not in the initial lookupset....not just the ones based on the genre that is in the initial set

Comment: @pythoncarrot sorry I missed the 's' placeholder. Corrected it. Also changed to fix the other problem. Now it will print only the genres the user already watched and not seen the movie yet.

Comment: Are you able to comment your code in terms of what the placeholders do and how sets work. I am unfamiliar with them but like your solution. Thanks again. Have upvoted

Comment: Updated my answer with comments. Please ask if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `str.split()` and `str.join()` functions:

```
# change file paths with your actual ones
with open('./text_files/user.txt', 'r') as userfile:
    viewed = userfile.read().split('\n')
    viewed_genders = set(g.split(',')[0] for g in viewed)

with open('./text_files/films.txt', 'r') as filmsfile:
    films = filmsfile.read().split('\n')
    not_viewed = [f for f in films
                  if f.split(',')[1] in viewed_genders and ','.join(f.split(',')[1:3]) not in viewed]

print('\n'.join(not_viewed))
```

The output:

```
3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG,0
4,Sci-Fi,Cosmos, PG,0
10,Romance, You've got mail, 12, 0
11,Romance, Last Tango in Paris, 18, 0
12,Romance, Casablanca, 12, 0
```

Comment: Are you able to comment the code for each line and what it is doing - that would be most helpful in terms of understanding the logic. Also, on trying exactly what you've suggested, the following error occurs;     if f.split(',')[1] in viewed_genres and ','.join(f.split(',')[1:3]) not in viewed]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @pythoncarrot, there should not be any errors, I've tested it on the contents you have posted - it works fine. Check your code for errors, also check if there are extra columns within some of your files.

Comment: the error persists:     if f.split(',')[1] in viewed_genres and  ','.join(f.split(',')[1:3]) not in viewed]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: such an error may occur only if actual contents of those files differ from those you've posted. Post the actual contents, or remove extra whitespaces from your files